# redactor.js Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, redactor

Even using the repo https://github.com/dybskiy/redactor-js/blob/master/demo/all_uploads.html
, when I drag and drop an image, I receive the error with jQuery.

```
parseJSON: function(n) 
{
    return e.JSON && e.JSON.parse ? e.JSON.parse(n) : null === n ? n : "string" == typeof n && (n = st.trim(n), n && dt.test(n.replace(gt, "@").replace(mt, "]").replace(ht, ""))) ? Function("return " + n)() : (st.error("Invalid JSON: " + n), t)
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Looks like you have html somewhere that should be json

Comment: And with what `n` value do you call that method?

Comment: Also, which version of jQuery are you using? Which version of jQuery does the upload plugin recommend?

Comment: I use  jquey.1.9.0 also used jquery.2.0.3 I recibe the same error